# Create a special dictionary<T, EventDelegate<T>> with generic delegate EventDelegate<T>(T e) where T : GameEventBase

Tags: c#, events, generics, dictionary

I have a game with many classes that need to listen to events. But under certain circumstances, those classes are destroyed or disabled. When that happens, I need to remove their listening methods from the events manager delegate table.

I don't want to modify the `EventsManager` and I would like to each class that adds any events to it to know which events it added.

I'm currently using something like this do add and remove the events in each class:

```
void AddEventsListeners() {        
    EventsManager.AddListener<OnClickDown>(OnClickDownHandler);
    EventsManager.AddListener<OnClickUp>(OnClickUpHandler);
    EventsManager.AddListener<OnClick>(OnClickHandler);
}

void RemoveEventsListeners() {
    EventsManager.RemoveListener<OnClickDown>(OnClickDownHandler);
    EventsManager.RemoveListener<OnClickUp>(OnClickUpHandler);
    EventsManager.RemoveListener<OnClick>(OnClickHandler);
}
```

Those `OnClick`  are all derived from `GameEventBase`, and the `OnClickHandler` are methods declared as

```
void OnClickDown(OnClickHandler e) {}
```

to match the delegate that is used in the `EventsManager`, which is declared as

```
delegate void EventDelegate<T>(T e) where T : GameEventBase;
```

I want to be able to fill a special hash table named, say, `events`, that has keyvalue pairs like

```
<T, EventDelegate<T>> where T: GameEventBase
```

That is, I want to be able to do `events.add(OnClick, OnClickHandler)`, where `OnClickHandler` is declared as

```
OnClickHandler(OnClick e) {}
```

And I want adding to fail if `OnClickHandler` where defined, for example, as

```
OnClickHandler(OtherGameEventBaseDerivedEvent e) {}
```

That requirement translates to me wanting type safety in that special dictionary.

One of my attempts involved not a dictionary, but a way to decide which method to call, between the `AddListener` and `RemoveListener`
I didn't like it because it introduces a parameter to the method and the code reads really weird with it. It does work, and does reduce the repetition, but is too ugly.

I create a `AddOrRemoveAllListeners(AddOrRemove addOrRemove)`, which I populated with calls to `AddOrRemoveListener` for each event.

Now all I had to do is `AddOrRemoveAllListeners(AddOrRemove.Remove)` or `AddOrRemoveAllListeners(AddOrRemove.Add)`, to add or remove my events.

```
enum AddOrRemove {
    Remove,
    Add
}

void AddOrRemoveListener<T>(EventsManager.EventDelegate<T> del, AddOrRemove addOrRemove) 
    where T : GameEventBase {

    switch (addOrRemove) {
        case AddOrRemove.Remove:
            EvMan.RemoveListener<T>(del);
            break;
        case AddOrRemove.Add:
            EvMan.AddListener<T>(del);
            break;
    }
}
```

Another attempt involved creating the type

```
class EventsDictionary<T> : Dictionary<T, EventsManager.EventDelegate<T>> where T : GameEventBase { }
```

And using it like this:

```
EventsDictionary<GameEventBase> events = new MyCustomDictionary<GameEventBase>();

void AddEventHandlerPairToEventsDictionary<T>(T e, EventsManager.EventDelegate<T> handler) where T : GameEventBase {
    if (!events.ContainsKey(e)) {
        events.Add(e, handler);
    }
}
```

But the `events.Add(e, handler)` fails and forces me to declare the `handler` as

```
EventsManager.EventDelegate<GameEventBase>
```

instead of

```
EventsManager.EventDelegate<T>
```

If I do that, I could add keyvalue pairs that don't make sense in that `events` type, i.e., I lose the event handling type safety.

---

I want to have such a structure because I don't like all those repetitions. It would be really bad if someone forgot to remove an event in the `RemoveEventsListeners()`.

Having such a dictionary, I could use a foreach loop to add/remove the handlers to the `EventsManager`, which would be really nice.

As for performance, this is for a game and it needs to have good performance. Those adding/removing of events can happen a lot (sometimes hundreds of times per frame) because a lot of objects are destroyed (can't leave null handlers in the EventsManager) or disabled (need to stop listening to everything until enabled again) all the time. This means reflection and lots of casting/boxing or anything that creates lots of garbage collected objects is out.

I'm, of course, open to suggestions as to other ways to approach this.

Thanks for your assistance!

---

I'm attaching the relevant parts of the EventsManager being used (The RemoveListener() is analogous to the AddListener). The GameEventBase is just an empty shell. It isn't a .NET event nor uses EventArgs.

```
public class EventsManager : ManagedBase {
    public delegate void EventDelegate<T>(T e) where T : GameEventBase;

    private delegate void EventDelegate(GameEventBase e);

    private readonly Dictionary<Type, EventDelegate> delegates = new Dictionary<Type, EventDelegate>();
    private readonly Dictionary<Delegate, EventDelegate> delegateLookup = new Dictionary<Delegate, EventDelegate>();

    public void AddListener<T>(EventDelegate<T> del) where T : GameEventBase {
        // Early-out if we've already registered this delegate
        if (delegateLookup.ContainsKey(del)) {
            return;
        }
        // Create a new non-generic delegate which calls our generic one.
        // This is the delegate we actually invoke.
        EventDelegate internalDelegate = (e) => del((T) e);
        delegateLookup[del] = internalDelegate;
        EventDelegate tempDel;
        if (delegates.TryGetValue(typeof (T), out tempDel)) {
            delegates[typeof (T)] = tempDel + internalDelegate;
        }
        else {
            delegates[typeof (T)] = internalDelegate;
        }
    }    

        public void Raise(GameEventBase e) {
        EventDelegate del;
        if (delegates.TryGetValue(e.GetType(), out del)) {
            del.Invoke(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have event handlers with different argument types, which your code will have to know when invoking the handlers. Any considerations regarding covariance and generics type parameters aside, trying to put all your different event handlers in a single dictionary will result in losing the information about what argument needs to be passed to a particular event handler. Either you would need to store that information somewhere else (yet another dictionary to look up from, a struct?), or use reflection. Either way, it would not look to be very maintainable code nor would it perform well, i guess

Comment: PS. One of the issues here is that event handlers aren't first class constructs in C#, and thus you can't pass them into methods.

Comment: I just added the relevant portion of the EventsManager. It was gotten from Will Miller's blog [here](http://www.willrmiller.com/?p=87). I found Will's implementation to be very nice, much better than mine that was using .NET events and delegates (too much boilerplate code for each event)

Comment: You are implementing something very similar to the Microsoft Prism library's EventAggregator. Except you don't have all of the threading and weak reference features that you get for free by using a library. Square Wheel syndrome.

Comment: @Aron as per Mare Infinitus's (and your) suggestion, I'm taking a look into that EventAggregator right now! I wonder how it'll fare with Unity3D's mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems seem to be solved if you use the EventAggregator pattern.

There is a short description of it [by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)

Some very good implementations of it already exist, for example in [caliburn micro](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/) and
[Microsoft Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)

The general idea is that you simplify event registration and deregistration and have a single source of events for many objects.

I never had performance issues with it. You simply put a _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this) when you want to start listening to events for an object and Unsubscribe if you want to stop. Whereever you want to fire an event, just publish it, EventAggregator does the routing.

Comment: I'm taking a look at that. It just might be that the EventsManager I'm using isn't the ideal one for this scenario. Thanks! Although this seems to have the same problem I want to avoid: I don't want to call Unsubscribe for every event I subscribed. I want a way to look through a list of events I subscribed to and perform the Subscribe/Unsubscribe directly on the elements of that list.

Comment: You do not call Unscribe per event, but per class. Your class implements eventhandlers and the EventAggregator does the job of dispatching. If your object is no longer interested in events, it just unsubscribes itself from the eventaggregator. So if your class handles the events a, b, c: you call Subscribe and events a, b, c are routed to your object. You do NOT need a list, this is all handled by the eventaggregator. Have a look, it is very strong a good choice for a lot of scenarios, especially yours.

Comment: I'm taking a look a Prism right now. It does seem better than what I have (don't know about performance yet, but looks good). It seems that this is the right direction!

Comment: I have used the caliburn micro implementation in many projects. As I was in fear of threading problems, I have written massive tests against it. And: There never were issues, all events were delivered properly and there were also no threading issues. Even with 20 Event Sources and 100 Event Consumers in parallel, firing events non stop

Comment: Oh, that is extremely reassuring! Checking caliburn micro instead or Prism right now. I most likely won't be able to use this in the current project, but will do so in the next (I might write a facade to use it in the current one if I find it worth of) Thanks for that!

Comment: As it solves so many problems that you currently have and is so easy to establish, you should throughly check that option

Answer (score 1):

This once again looks like an XY problem. OP seems to want to have a central place to handle event handlers, registration and disposal. The OP has gone down the route of trying to create a pattern that deal with this in a generic way, but has not looked into the state of the art regarding how this problem is typically solved. He has now come up against a problem in his design and is now asking for a solution to THAT problem, rather than the original problem of event handlers.

There are two good solutions to event handler registration lifecycle management that I know of in .net.

**Weak Event Handler**

You state that "It would be really bad if someone forgot to remove an event in the `RemoveEventsListeners()`." Yet do not actually mention WHY it is bad. Typically the only reason for this being bad is that the event handler will now keep an object in reference, that should be collected. With weak reference event handlers, the GC will still be able to collect your object, even when it subscribes to an object that is still alive.

**Rx.Net**

Rx.Net abstracts event registrations into IDisposables, which you can tie to the object's lifetime, assuming of course you want to control the lifetime of the registrations.

However I actually find the `IObservable` pattern much nicer to work with than event handler pattern, mostly because C# lacks first class support for event handlers (this is not the case with F#).

**F#**

Most of your problems will have stemmed from the short sighted design of events keyword handling in C# (specifically not making events a first class construct). F# however does support first class events, and thus should be able to support the pattern you are trying to construct.

Thus with this option you should scrap your code base and rewrite it in F#.

*EDIT added tongue in cheek option of rewriting in F#.

Comment: I'm language bind to C# in this case. Also, I mentioned that I can't make changes to the EventsManager, so it isn't the XY problem but the X problem itself. I mentioned that objects are destroyed of deactivated all the time and that is why it would be bad if one forgets to remove the event in `RemoveEventsListeners()`: you would have a null method reference (because the object was destroyed) or a method that should not fire (because the object was deactivated, not the same as destroyed).

Comment: @Fausto you didn't say you can't make changes, you said you didn't want to. However it is a bad API. You noted pain points, which arises from deficits of C#, but do not want to fix the underlying issue, which is that the pattern you chose does not work with C#. I have given you 2 realistic options, and Mare Infinitus's suggestion is also pretty good.

Comment: Due to the large size of this project, changing the EventsManager now (which about everything is using already) would be really bad, that is why I really don't want to change it. I can even say I can't, since other would possibly kill me if I forced a new system like that. The pain point is almost syntactic sugar, I just want to be able to look through a list and perform the add/remove event on the elements of that list. See my edit to the original question. I included a portion of the EventsManager. How bad is it?